# Child component execute method before parent component - Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I have `DataStorageServiceService` service where I have `getCategory` method which call date from the server and I have another server where I have method `getCategoryFromServer`which  execute `getCategory` method and store data on the `Array`. I have component `ProductsComponent` were in `constructor` I execute `getCategoryFromServer` and work with `Array`. I the `ProductsComponent` I have 2 components `ProductListItemsComponent` and `SingleProductComponent`. This is simple examples of code:

This is method `getCategory`:

```
 /** GET Category from the server */
  getCategory(): Observable<CategoryModel[]> {
    return this.http.get<CategoryModel[]>(this.cateogryUrl).pipe(

      catchError(this.handleError('getProduct', []))
    )
  }
```

This is method `getCategoryFromServer` :

```
 getCategoryFromServer() {
    this.dataStorageServiceServiceta.getCategory().subscribe((category: CategoryModel[]) => {
      this.categoryModule = category;
      this.cateogoryChange.next(this.categoryModule.slice())
    })
  }
```

Component `ProductsComponent` :

```
 constructor(private productsService: ProductsService) {
    this.productsService.getCategoryFromServer();
  }
```

Everything good but when I refresh page first done children component method and after that my `getCategoryFromServer` and that make problems.
I want to mention, I using routing for my children component, and dependency of `url` : `id` children component is shown. 
This is template for `ProductsComponent`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: I am not sure it will help, but try move `this.productsService.getCategoryFromServer();` from constructor to `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook. Constructors are only required for dependency injection. It is not recommended to place your application logic here.

Comment: This is not solve my problem. Is this a good approach with my services? What you think?

Comment: I am not sure the problem is, but I think it should be `lifecycle` issue. maybe you can try it, or post more complete code show us